# How to close my popup and stay at same place on referring page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a popup and when I close it the page I should go back to scrolls up. How can I avoid having the referring page scroll all the way up when I close my popup? I'd like the referring page to stay where it's at.

My code to close the popup is

`<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('popupD').style.display = 'none';"
" align="right">Close</a>`

How can it be done in the way I want?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing how you've created your popup, it's hard to say anything exact. However, it seems, that you have a `DIV`-element positioned relative into the text flow. Just position the popup out of the text flow using `position:absolute` or `position:fixed`.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace `href="#"` with `href="javascript://"`

Answer (score 1):

I think the following would help you.

```
$('#popupD , .popup_block').fadeOut(function() {
    $('#popupD, a.close').remove();  //fade them both out
});
```

Cheers...!!!